# isNaN() javascript, number with 2 commas

Tags: javascript, random, numbers, setinterval, percentage

I'm working with percentage and the `setInterval()` so I have a

```js
    var intervalId;
    function randomize(){
       var prc = $("#prc").val();
       var c = 0 ;
       if (!intervalId){
          intervalId = setInterval(function(){
              c = c + 1;
              var attempt = Math.random() * 100;
              if (attempt <= prc){
                  clearInterval(intervalId);
                  intervalId = false;
                  $("#attemptnbr").val(c);
              }
          }, 100);
       }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Percentage : <input type="text" id="prc"/>
<button onclick="randomize()">GO</button>
Number of attempts :<input type="text" id="attemptnbr"/>
```

But actually if the user set the `#prc` input to `50.345.34`, the `attempt <= prc` condition always returns `true`. 
I tried to `console.log(isNaN(prc))` when this input is set to a number like `50.345.34` and it always returns `false`.

Why is it considered as a numeric value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But actually if the user set the #prc input to 50.345.34, the attempt <= prc condition always returns true.

Pretty sure that's observation error. Your `prc` is a string, which will then be implicitly converted to a number by the `<=` operator. The number will be `NaN` because "50.345.34" can't be implicitly converted, and relations using `NaN` are never true.

However it doesn't really change what you want to do about it, which is convert `prc` to a number *on purpose* and test the result:

```
var intervalId;
function randomize(){
   var prc = +$("#prc").val();
   //        ^------------------- Note the +, that converts it to a number
   if (isNaN(prc)) {
       // Handle the invalid input
       return;
   }
   var c = 0 ;
   if (!intervalId){
      intervalId = setInterval(function(){
          c = c + 1;
          var attempt = Math.random() * 100;
          if (attempt <= prc){
              clearInterval(intervalId);
              intervalId = false;
              console.log(attempt);
          }
      }, 100);
   }
}
```

I should note that the above may do something you don't want if the input is *empty*: It will use the value `0`, because `+""` is `0`. If you don't want that, you might do this:

```
var prcString = $.trim($("#prc").val());
var prc = +prcString;
if (!prcString) {
    // Handle the fact they didn't enter anything
    return;
}
if (isNaN(prc)) {
    // Handle the invalid input
    return;
}
```

Comment: Is this input value not a number even if  `<input type="number" name="prc">` ?

Comment: @TerryRapt: Yes, the `value` of an `input` is *always* a string, even for the new input types. jQuery's `val` will only ever return a string (if there are any elements in the jQuery set you call it on) or `undefined` (if the set is completely empty, but that doesn't apply in your case I assume).

Comment: Thanks for all these informations, it really helped me.

Comment: @TerryRapt: My pleasure. I added a note to the end I should have had there earlier.

Comment: _"50.345.34" can't be converted.._ Aren't the same rules as with [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) applied when a string implicitly converted to number? (so "50.345.34" => `50`)

Comment: @hindmost: No. `parseInt` and `parseFloat` stop at the first invalid character, returning the number at the *beginning* of the string if any. But `Number` and implicit conversion (as with `<=`, the unary `+` I used above, or `*` or `/` or `-`) convert (or fail to convert) the **whole** string. So `parseInt("50.345.34")` is `50`, `parseFloat("50.345.34")` is `50.345`, and `+"50.345.34"` is `NaN`. Unfortunately (in my view), there's an odd exception, which is that implicit conversion converts a blank string(`""`) to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `$("#prc").val()` returns a string. `50.345.34` is a string. <s>When you compare string and number, js will be compare string length and number value.</s>

Comment: *"When you compare string and number, js will be compare string length and number value."* No. When you use a relational operator on a string and a number, the string is implicitly converted to a number, and then the two numbers are compared.